# Time of day greeting using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, datetime

I am working on a school project where the requirement is to execute greeting based on the current time using jQuery. The teacher wants me to do this using   jQuery elements, selectors and filters as well as event handlers. I have been able to get the program working using jQuery but I am having an issue with all the requirements that they have in place. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var msg;

        if (hours < 12) msg = "Good Morning!";
        else if (hours < 18) msg = "Good Afternoon!";
        else msg = "Good Evening!";
    $('#time').html('<p>'+msg+'</p>');
    });

    $(":text").css("color", "red");
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="time">
        <p>+msg+</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know exactly where I'm going wrong. I think it is with the placement of my filter outside the function and whether I am meeting all requirements. I am very new to jQuery and having a bit of a hard time with it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem, where is it failing

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/px76L5dz/1/

Comment: what do you expect `$(":text").css("color", "red");` to do?

Comment: may be https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/px76L5dz/2/ ? - The selector `:text` is invalid here as it looks for a `input type="text"` element, you need to color the `#time` element, also need to move it to the dom ready handler

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this using filters? That's why I had written it this way. Or is there a possibility anywhere in this program for filters?

Comment: Just for the sake of using filter -> `$('#time > *').filter('p').html(msg);`, but really it should be `$('#time p').html(msg);`

Comment: I tried this I'm not sure if this quite works

Comment: $(":contains(msg)").css("color", "red");

Comment: There is no filter used here, it is just a selector... what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: Just some kind of filter, I'll just use what you suggested.

Comment: You haven't been specific enough with your morning and afternoon checks. I reckon you should: if (hours < 12) msg = "Good Morning!";
        else if (hours < 18 & num >= 12) msg = "Good Afternoon!";
        else msg = "Good Evening!"; then your messages will be correct according to the time. Right now you get both morning and afternoon messages if the time is < 18.